# How to make Frame from Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I have aplet and I'm trying to make simple frame from that.
Should I only change extends Apllet to extends JFrame

```
public class Main extends Applet {

    public void init() {

    }
}
```

I fixed it to:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main () {

    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Main m1 = new Main();
        m1.setVisible(true);
        m1.setSize(300, 300);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE!**

[THERE IS MY CODE - PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/WTY0gcaT)

Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at stack.WireframeViewer.<init>(WireframeViewer.java:67)
    at stack.WireframeViewer.main(WireframeViewer.java:162)
```

Comment: *"It doesn't work."* - honestly, doesn't mean much

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: Is the paint method different in applet and swing?

Comment: 1) *"Is the paint method different in applet and swing?"*  An applet might be AWT **or** Swing, so that question makes no sense.   Swing and AWT paint slightly differently, but not in any way that is relevant to the code above. 2) The applet code does nothing useful, so I'm not sure what you expected to see.

Comment: Update, I added my code. I try to fix it to using Frame, could you tell me what is wrong? Eclipse told me that something with that: `backg = backbuffer.getGraphics();`

Comment: *"Update, I added my code."* No, you added a link to it.  The code needs to be included in this question.  Did you take the advice offered by @MadProgrammer in that question?  If not, do that now.  Is the problem in that question resolved?  If so, please accept an answer.

Comment: *"Eclipse told me that something with that: `backg = backbuffer.getGraphics();`"*  Seriously, how can we have any idea what Eclipse told you?  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry, it's my bad. Can you check my question? I think now is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy. You were on the right way to achieve this. Extend your class from `JFrame` instead of `Applet` and add a main method as you already did.
But here you need to write it this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Main main = new Main();
    main.setSize(300, 300);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.init();
}
```

Regard the last call here! You need to invoke your `init` method manually since this is something automatic for Applets but not for JFrames. And this must be done after `setVisible` because you will not get the `width` and `height` of your frame before.

Additionally you have to remove your `showStatus(...)` call in your `paint` method because this is something for Applets. In JFrames your need to add a `JLabel` or `JTextField` for this.

Comment: Updated my answer! Should work with your Applet code now.

Comment: thanks! :) I remove `showStatus`. It works! But how can I fix my `init` method to `Main` constructor? I'm trying to make "clear" JFrame code and I want to use without `main.init();`.

Comment: Put the content of your `init` method in constructor but regard that the first lines are `setSize` and `setVisible` from the `main` method. You need to know that without have called `setSize` before your will not get a result for `getSize`. And without have called `setVisible` before, you will not get a result for `getGraphics`.